# How to design a reusable dialog for creating new instances of an entity and how to pass them back to the backing bean?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, dialog, composite-component

I am currently trying to design a reusable dialog for creating a new entity instance.

**Problem situation:**
In my view there is a dynamic list of entities, for which I have a selectOne-Dropdown to select an existing entity an also a button, that one may click to open a create-dialog for a creating a new instance of this entity class, if the correct one is missing.

**Attemp for solution:**
I tried to create a composite component for this issues which looks like this:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="myBean" required="true"
        type="interfaces.INewEntity" />
    <composite:attribute name="target" required="true"
        type="entity.SsoUser" />        
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{cc.attributes.target}" >
        // selectItems 
        // ...      
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:commandButton type="buton" value="new" onclick="PF('a').show()"  />

    <p:dialog id="test" widgetVar="a">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="newPanelGrid">
            <h:outputText value="Set some properties.." />
            <p:inputText value="#{cc.attributes.myBean.newEntity.foo}" />               
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton value="Create new Entity" process="test" update="@form"
            oncomplete="PF('a').hide()"
            actionListener="#{cc.attributes.myBean.save()}">
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:dialog>

</composite:implementation>
```

After persisting the new entity the dropdown now contains the new entity instance.

**Problem:** I want to somehow set the value from the dropdown menu to the new created entity. How could this be achieved?

---

**A static example**:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable, INewEntity {

    // comes from the interfaces
    private Entity newEntity;

    // some persistent fields 
    private Wrapper wrap;

    // ...
}

public class Wrapper {
    Entity a,b,c;
}
```

And I am using my CC this way:

```
   <stg:mycc target="#{myBean.wrap.a}" userBean="#{myBean}" />
   <stg:mycc target="#{myBean.wrap.b}" userBean="#{myBean}" />
   <stg:mycc target="#{myBean.wrap.c}" userBean="#{myBean}" />
```

Comment: I added a short static example. In my real problem the Entity `a,b,c` are from a collection that I am iterating over. Now I want to use the same create dialog for all Entities a,b,c. Some of them might be `null`, some not. The missing part is how to get the new Entity, which is at the moment stored in `newEntity` to the correct reference for either `a` `b` or `c`

Comment: @BalusC i will try to reformulate my question ans provide a full working example. Unfortunately not earlier than tomorrow.